# Problems building libcurl 7.21.2 on Ubuntu 11.10 (Hiphop)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libcurl, hiphop

I'm following this Hiphop installation guide:

https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Building-and-installing-on-ubuntu-10.10

And when I try to `make` it, I get the following errors:

```
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSLv2_client_method'
```

I've found this Server Fault ticket, but the merged change from the [linked Github pull request](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/pull/322) didn't seem to fix the problem.

https://superuser.com/questions/339932/compiling-curl-with-hiphop-for-php-patch

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, but I doubt that's the issue.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

EDIT: Adding Hiphop Cmake errors:

Here are errors when I just try to `cmake .` while ignoring the libcurl problems:

```
CMake Error at CMake/HPHPFindLibs.cmake:90 (message):
  Custom libcurl is required with the HipHop patch
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/HPHPSetup.cmake:46 (include)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.10 uses OpenSSL v1.0. OpenSSL v1.0 has (finally!) disabled SSLv2 support entirely.

Curl can build against nosslv2 OpenSSL starting from 7.21.5.

You can port the changes in 7.21.5 that allow such builds back to your custom libcurl. Alternatively, you can build a private version of OpenSSL that includes SSLv2 support, and link your custom libcurl against it.

Comment: While I didn't use your suggestions, your diagnosis of the problem was spot on. I just wiped my VM and installed Ubuntu 10.10, and the Github instructions worked mostly perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on 11.10.
@n.m was exactly right on this problem....
I inserted the following lines of code:

```
#ifdef OPENSSL_NO_SSL2
   failf(data, "openSSL was compiled without SSLv2 support");
   return CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR;
#endif
```

after line 1462

Please find these lines of code here  :  github.com/bagder/curl/commit/26b487a5d6ed9da5bc8e4a134a88d3125884b852

in curl/lib/ssluse.c

recompiled and built... 
Seems to work now!

Comment: Awesome, I look forward to checking it out!