# Error building libcurl 7.21.2 on Ubuntu 11.10 when installing Hiphop

Tags: ubuntu, libcurl, ubuntu-11.10, hiphop

I'm following this guide to install Hiphop on Ubuntu 11.10:

http://societyofcode.com/articles/guide_getting_started_with_hiphop_for_php-01-04-12

When I try command `cmake .` then i get errors:

```
-- CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH was missing, proceeding anyway
-- MySQL Include dir: /usr/include  library dir: /usr/lib
-- MySQL client libraries: mysqlclient_r
-- Found libevent: /home/dakiquang/dev/lib/libevent.so
-- Found GD: /usr/lib/libgd.so
-- Looking for curl_multi_select
-- Looking for curl_multi_select - not found
CMake Error at CMake/HPHPFindLibs.cmake:90 (message):
  Custom libcurl is required with the HipHop patch
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/HPHPSetup.cmake:46 (include)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I following this page trying  to install HipHop for Ubuntu 11.10:
https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Building-and-Installing-on-Ubuntu-11.10
, but result is the same error.

I've found the same quesion in [Problems building libcurl 7.21.2 on Ubuntu 11.10 (Hiphop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287515/problems-building-libcurl-7-21-2-on-ubuntu-11-10-hiphop) , and I change libcurl 7.21.2 to libcurl 7.21.5 but result is the same error.

How to fix this error ?

Comment: Were you able to get hiphop working?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Hiphop authors have decided they need to patch libcurl to bring in the curl_multi_select function.

The upstream libcurl project (which I lead) has rejected the patch as provided to them, so the only way you can get a libcurl with that function available is to build your own libcurl from source with that patch applied.

There have been efforts to make hiphop not require that extra patch but I don't know where they ended.

I think it is unfortunate that the Hiphop people have taken this route, but they are of course perfectly allowed to do so.